# Accessing a property of Range from a scripting.Dictionary item (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

As mentioned in the title, I'm wondering if something like this is valid:

Let's suppose my_dict is filled with Excel.Ranges

```
Public my_dict as new scripting.dictionary 
Set my_dict = new scripting.dictionary

Dim random as variant

'Is the following line possible ?

Random = my_dict.item(key).Columns.Count

'Or should i do this ?

Dim temp_var as variant
temp_var = my_dict.item(key)
Random = temp_var.Columns.Count
```

Comment: 'Random = my_dict.item(key).Columns.Count' is perfectly ok but does not provide intellisense.  The more correct way to write this code is to assign the dictionary Item to a range object  e.g. 'Dim myRange as Range:set myRange = myDict.Item(key)'.  this will allow intellisense on the myRange object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to read the `Range` out of the dictionary, you have a small error in your code. When you write

```
Dim temp_var as variant
temp_var = my_dict.item(key)
```

the VBA runtime will see that the object that is stored as item is a Range. Using the `=` to a Range will copy the *content* of the Range, so you end up with a 2-dimensional array (except if the range contains only one single cell). To get the number of columns, you then would have to use `UBound`:

```
Random = UBound(temp_var, 2)
```

When you want to access the `Range`-object, you will need to use `Set`:

```
Dim temp_var as variant
Set temp_var = my_dict.item(key)
```

Besides that, using an intermediate variable doesn't make a difference to the first statement you use, the result will be the same. Yes, the first statement is valid when the item is a `Range`.

However, if I where you, I would always go for the intermediate variable, but don't use `Variant` as data type but `Range`. This helps the compiler to catch errors (eg missing the keyword `Set`), makes the code more readable and gives you the benefit of intellisense in the VBA editor. Also, my advice would be to use clearer variable names:

```
Dim tempRange as Range
Set tempRange = my_dict.item(key)
Random = tempRange.Columns.Count
```

Comment: Thanks for your time & your clear explanation !

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Set`-keyword to retrieve the range.

```vb
Dim rgRandom As Range
Set rgRandom = my_dict.Item(Key)

Dim cntColumns As Long
cntColumns = rgRandom.Columns.Count
```